# SecurityException - Unknown calling package name -Android 6.0.1

Tags: android, security, android-6.0-marshmallow

My app is on app store for since over than two years, I recieved this crash on Crashlytics for the last two builds, only for Android devices with "Android 6.0.1"

```
**Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException

Unknown calling package name 'my_package_name'.**

android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1620)

android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1573)

com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzs$zza$zza.zza (Unknown Source)

com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj.zza (Unknown Source)

com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlg$zzf.zznO (Unknown Source)

com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlg$zzi.run (Unknown Source)

java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:423)

java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:237)

java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker 
(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)

java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run 
(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)

java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm also getting the same error log. any solution??

Comment: +1 API level 19 / LG-D959. Curiously enough, I am seeing this using Firebase  Crash Reporting, and the only device reporting the issue has / had a connection state properly of "disconnected". Maybe has something to do with it?

Comment: hi did you find a valid solution for this issue? thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I had same issue and reached to user who gets crash by phone. User says that he cloned my app with a third party application and he's trying to use both apps in same device and gets crash.

With a quick search, i found some applications in Google Play which clones apps.

I'm not sure if there's a valid way for handling this crash such as trying to get support from Google or is it right to take action for this issue. For now, i'll ignore the crashes cause only 1 user gets these crashes.

Good luck.